# What does audit mode in Sysprep do?

Tags: windows, deployment, audit, sysprep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the audit mode of SYSPREP practically useful in Windows deployment?](https://serverfault.com/questions/75505/is-the-audit-mode-of-sysprep-practically-useful-in-windows-deployment)

The MS docs say when you should use it, and for what, but I can't find any description of what going into Audit mode actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what answer you're looking for.  You say you've checked the MS documentation (by which I assume you mean [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722413(WS.10).aspx)), but I would say this gives a more than ample explanation of what Audit mode actually does.  Is there something specific about the process you're wondering about?